# "detoured from the battleground states that will decide the election for a stop in California"

Tags: sentence-meaning

Currently reading [**this line**](https://news.yahoo.com/trumps-cash-crunch-constrains-campaign-193033654.html), there is a line

> To close the budgetary shortfall, Trump has slashed millions of dollars in previously reserved television ads and **detoured from the battleground states that will decide the election for a stop in California** last weekend to refill his campaign coffers. He has also tried to jump-start his online fundraising with increasingly aggressive tactics, sending out as many as 14 email solicitations in a day.

Would this line mean that Trump virtually stopped all the campaign in California to garner money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that he has not gone to the battleground states, but has gone to California, to remain there for a time ("a stop"). That delay is to replenish his campaign funds, maybe by a combination of stopping spending and asking for more money from donors.